# Improving EV3 Screen Readability

Tags: ev3

I often have a hard time reading the EV3’s LCD display. I presume that I’m not the only one who has experienced this issue. Is there a way to improve its readability?

For example, are there any good magnifiers that fit, or any ways to add backlighting or mirror the displays to a larger screen?

Answer (score 2):

One guy found a way to make the EV3 Brick's screen have light on it like it is on any device, but if you think training for soldering and blowing $30 just to see your EV3's screen is not worth it, you might as well use a lamp.

Here's the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gPNJC5Uz9HY&t=0s